# Explicit cast of dynamic method return value within a method doesn't allow an extension method to be called

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, dynamic

The following code demonstrates my question:

```cs
public class DynamicExample
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        var x = new ExpandoObject();
        dynamic d = x;
        d.GetString = (Func<string>)(() => "Some Value");

        d.GetString().SomeStringExtension(); // Doesn't work - expected
        ((string)d.GetString()).SomeStringExtension(); // Works - expected
        Build(d).SomeStringExtension(); // Doesn't work - unexpected?
    }

    private static string Build(dynamic d)
    {
        return (string)d.GetString();
    }
}

public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static int SomeStringExtension(this string s)
    {
        return s.Length;
    }
}
```

The question is, why is there a difference for the compiler between casting the type inline to the extension method call and moving that cast out into a separate method?

Comment: +1 As an added question: why in `var s = Build(d);` the `var` is dynamic? (I'll add that this, is probably, the real question. If the result of `Build(d)` is implicitly dynamic, then the resolution of `SomeStringExtension` can't be done at runtime)

Comment: It doesn't work because `dynamic` is telling the compiler to stop doing type analysis on the variable. How do you expect it to match up extension methods without that information? The explicate cast works because your explicitly casting to a known compile time type.

Comment: Agreed. I suspect that the compiler is deciding that the whole of the Build(dynamic d) method must be subject to dynamic linking, but I don't understand the reason why. (Going to edit the question to get rid of the multiple Build methods - in such a way as to keep these comments valid.)

Comment: @dlev The OP thought that dynamic in this case was similar to object and that method resolution was done at compile time instead that at runtime. So that `dynamic c = "Hello"`; `FunctionWithMultipleOverloads(c);` wouldn't have chose the "most right" overload and would have been equivalent to `object c = "Hello";`. I'll add "me too" :-)

Comment: @xanatos At runtime a mini version of the compiler is ran that does the dynamic resolution before the method overload resolution happens. Or at least something close to that, I'm a little murky on the exact details. It's laid out exactly in the spec.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Build(d)` is still a dynamic expression - the compile-time type of the method is `dynamic` even though *you* can see exactly what's going on. That means extension methods won't work.

Basically the compiler follows reasonably simple rules to determine what the type of an expression is, and almost *any* expression involving `dynamic` ends up being considered as a dynamic expression. The exceptions to this are:

- `d is SomeType` (always considered to be `bool`)
- Casts, both direct and using `as`

That's it as far as I can remember, although I could be mistaken...

Now the language *could* have been designed such that this case would *statically* resolve the call to `Build` as the only sensible one - after all, it's impossible for `d` to be of *any* type which would change which method is called - but to specify the exact rules for that would make the language specification (and the compiler) significantly more complicated for relatively little gain.

Comment: So you get to use overloads of methods (if overloads of Build where present, the right one would be chosen at runtime) but you lose the use of extension methods, right?

Comment: @xanatos: Without a cast or other conversion to a "known" type, yes.

Comment: I knew Jon wouldn't be far from this type of question! I'm accepting this answer because it explains that the cast is treated differently and thus explains why there's a difference between the last two attempts to call the extension method.

Answer (score 5):

If you hover over `Build(d)` in VS2010, you'll see that the entire expression is considered dynamic, and to be resolved at run-time. As such, it can't bind to the extension method (which would otherwise occur at compile-time.)

The reason the whole expression is `dynamic` is that without knowing the compile-time type of the argument, overload resolution <s>can't be</s> isn't performed, and so the return-type of the method <s>can't be</s> isn't known either.

Comment: In this case overload resolution *could* be performed, as the compiler *could* notice that there *is* a accessible method in this class, and it's the *only* accessible method, and it will always be valid for the argument type. But this is a relatively rare case.

Comment: That's why I think I'd use the word "isn't" rather than "can't" here :)

Comment: @JonSkeet it's even more rare of an instance than `Build` being the only accessible method, actually because `string` is sealed that technically the result of `Build` could only have the extension method named `SomeStringExtension`.  If say `Build` returned an unsealed type, it still could have returned a runtime-only known subclass with an instance method named `SomeStringExtension` then with the proper late binding behavior `Build(d).SomeStringExtension();` would work, but if the compiler assumed, as an exception to the rule, and resolved the `Build` call at compile time it would miss it.